Electrical types in KiCAD pins in custom symbol creation
I'm trying to make a symbol for this IC(DAC60501MDGSR) with the following pinout:

But in KiCAD for each pin I need to assign an "electrical type" from the dropdown menu:

Here below what I came up with so far:

My questions are:
1-) In my case, are the assignments correct?
2-) If I don't assign the electrical types correctly, would that be a problem?


In my case, are the assignments correct?

You could use unconnected rather than unspecified for pins marked NC (no connection). But, at the end of the day, if you are just using KiCAD for its schematic and PCB design features, it doesn't really matter how you assign pin attributes. However, there are some "rule checks" that KiCAD can perform where it looks for (say) two outputs connected to the same net and, KiCAD will flag that as a warning/error when you run the error checker.
I tend to make all pins passive except for power ins (including 0 volts, GND and AGND) because it can be a little annoying when too many irrelevant warnings crop up. But, that's down to you.

If I don't assign the electrical types correctly, would that be a
problem?

It won't be a problem hence why I only assign power pins and unconnected pins with their respective correct pin attributes. For the majority of the rest I select passive.


In my case, are the assignments correct?

Not quite. Try to follow the Pin Functions table 6-1 in the datasheet:

There need to be different alternate pin function definitions depending on whether the chip is configured for SPI or I2C, and whether the reference voltage pin is an input or output.



Name
DGS
6.1 Type
Default Type
Alt Type 1
Alt Type 2




AGND
4
Ground
Power Input




NC
3,9
--
Unconnected




SCLK
6
Input
Input SPI
Open Collector I2C



SDIN
8
Input/Output
Input SPI
Open Collector I2C



SPI2C
5
Input
Input




S̅Y̅N̅C̅/A0
7
Input
Input




VDD
1
Power
Power Input




VOUT
2
Output
Output




VREFIO
10
Input/Output
Input ext. ref.
Output int. ref.
Passive multi-fn.



Using Bidirectional as the electrical type for a pin that's either input or output but doesn't switch between the two is incorrect. The only setting I've found that plays with the default ERC rules is Passive for such pins. Thus, Passive should be an option when VREFIO is flips between an input and an output. But most likely you'll use a single configuration - either input or output, so the functions should be set to match that.

If I don't assign the electrical types correctly, would that be a problem?

It will be a problem since the Schematic ERC (electrical rules check) will detect those as errors. The general idea is that you should make the Electrical Types in the symbols interoperate with the ERC electrical type connection rules matrix. Even some of KiCad's own library symbols get it wrong sometimes.
